# On measures on profinite groups

Tags: number-theory, measure-theory, p-adic-number-theory, profinite-groups

A measure on a profinite group $\Gamma$ with values in a $p$-adic ring $\cal O$ and its reinterpretation as an element of the Iwasawa algebra $\Lambda_{\cal O}={\cal O}[[\Gamma]]$ are defined in textbooks under the hypothesis that $\cal O$ is the ring of integers in a finite extension of the field $\mathbb{Q}_p$ of $p$-adic numbers.

I understand that the reason of this is so that the Iwasawa algebra $\Lambda_{\cal O}$ is compact, although I am not sure exactly at what point this becomes useful.

In particular, I see no reason why the theory shouldn't work for any $p$-adic ring $\cal O$. After all in the case $\Gamma=\mathbb{Z}_p$ Mahler's theory of interpolation of $R$-valued continuous functions works for any ring $R$.

Comment: What's the question? And what is the definition of "a $p$-adic ring" you're working with, which apparently is more general than that of a ring of integers in a finite extension of $\mathbb Q_p$?

Comment: No idea for the compactness. But why not define the objects correctly ? $H_n\supset H_{n+1}$ are a sequence of normal subgroups such that $G/H_n$ is finite, $\bigcap H_n=\{1\}$, a $Z_p$-valued measure on $G$ is such that $\mu(A)=\lim_{n\to \infty} \mu(A H_n)$. 

Let $y_n=\sum_{gH_n\in G/H_n} \mu(gH_n)[gH_n]$. Then $(y_n)\in \varprojlim Z_p[G/H_n]$. Conversely which  elements $\sum_{gH_n\in G/H_n} a(gH_n)[gH_n]\in \varprojlim Z_p[G/H_n]$ give a $Z_p$-valued measure $\mu(A)=\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{gH_n\in A H_n} a(gH_n)$ ?